# How to create VHD file fixed size of window 2003 server

Tags: windows, azure, migration, vhd, microsoft

I am trying to create a VHD file fixed size of window 2003 R2 server.
As Hyper V role and Azure CLI is not supported i am not able to create it.
Though Disk2VD creates VHD file but it is dynamic.
Can someone tell me how to create VHD file of window 2003 R2 server fixed size ?
I am trying to migrate aws EC2 window 2003 to azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the VHD with Hyper-V Manager.

> Launch the Edit Disk action within Hyper-V Manager then select the
>   dynamic VHD. On the Action screen, shown here, select the Convert
>   option to make the dynamic VHD a fixed VHD. You'll be prompted for a
>   new name for the fixed VHD.

Comment: As per the microsoft doc. Hyper V role is not supported in Win 2003 server. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-windows-guest-operating-systems-for-hyper-v-on-windows

Comment: @GovindGupta You're not understanding. You use Disk2VHD to create your 2003 server disk, then you use Hyper-V on a supported server to convert it. Or use Powershell. You don't perform the conversion on the 2003 server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hyper-V Manager to make the conversion:

- select the **Edit Disk** option within **Hyper-V Manager**
- select the **dynamic VHD**
- on the **Action** screen select the **Convert** option to make the dynamic VHD a fixed VHD
- give a new name for the fixed VHD.

Alternately, from powershell you could use Convert-VHD cmdlet:

```
Convert-VHD -Path D:\HardDiskDyn.vhd -DestinationPath D:\HardDiskFixed.vhd -VHDType Fixed
```

For the command to work, you need to Import-Module ServerManager

Comment: As per the microsoft doc. Hyper V role is not supported in Win 2003 server. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-windows-guest-operating-systems-for-hyper-v-on-windows

Comment: @GovindGupta You're not understanding. You use Disk2VHD to create your 2003 server disk, then you use Hyper-V on a supported server to convert it. Or use Powershell. You don't perform the conversion on the 2003 server.

Comment: @Govind Gupta - you said you want to concert an image of Windows 2003 server, not that you try to accomplish this from a Windows 2003 server.

Comment: @Overmind - I have created a VHD file by using disk2VHD tool within the window 2003 server but that vhd file is dynamic so i have downloaded that vhd file on my windows 10 client server and convert is to fixed size vhd using Hyper V on the window 2010.  Is this is right approach ? as i am migrating this server to azure.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. You can do the conversion on anything supporting Hyper-V Manager.